# How to access actual JS settings of my module after ajax call?

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

I need to add some additional JS data for my views page.

I write in my module:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
if ($view->name == "myview") {

$outdata=array('dataset'=>my_custom_function_which_generates_data());
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $outdata), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/init.js');   
 }

 }
```

When the page loads, I can easily access to my data with JS using Drupal.settings.mymodule.dataset object.

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

    console.log(Drupal.settings.mymodule.dataset);  //this code executes on page load and on AJAX refresh of the view

    }

    }

    });
```

But I need to change/refresh data with each view executing when the view refreshes by AJAX.
When I use exposed filters and enable AJAX, I expect to get fresh data.

The view content refreshes normally. Also I see in FF console, that my fresh data of Drupal.settings.mymodule.dataset is in JSON.

But variable Drupal.settings.mymodule.dataset stays the same as on the page load when I access it in my code.
What are I doing wrong?
How to access fresh data of Drupal.settings.mymodule.dataset?

Comment: Have you looked at your JS aggregation or cache settings to see if they affect refresh results?

Comment: All caches and JS aggregation are disabled. Please note tha I wrote that I see fresh data in JSON response, but my JS can use data that loaded with whole page. If I refresh the page I can get and use fresh data, but I cant use fresh data with AJAX

Comment: Is your data present in the local `settings` object that's passed in to your `attach` function as the 2nd parameter? Perhaps there was an error that pervented jquery from merging the data into the global `Drupal.settings`?

Comment: No, when I try to console.log(settings) I get the same result with console.log(Drupal.settings). I see right data in JSON response only.